# R package VennDiagram: How can I print values outside the circles?

Tags: r, diagram, venn-diagram

Suppose:

- S={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
- A={1,2,3,4,5,6}
- B={6,7,8,9}
- A intersection B = {6}.

How can I represent these sets in a Venn diagram such that values outside the sets A and B (in this case, {10,11,12}) are printed outside the two circles?

This is the Venn Diagram I want:
[image: desired_venn_diagram]

But this is the Venn Diagram my code produces

[image: produced_venn_diagram]

How can I print "10", "11" and "12" outside the circles, as in the first picture?

This is my code:

```r
library(VennDiagram)
S<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
B<-c(6,7,8,9)
v<-venn.diagram(list(A=A,B=B),
                fill=c("orange","blue"),
                alpha=c(0.5,0.5),cat.cex=1.5,cex=1.5,
                filename=NULL)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v)
lapply(v,names)
lapply(v,function(i) i$label)
v[[5]]$label<-paste(setdiff(A,B),collapse="\n")
v[[6]]$label<-paste(setdiff(B,A ),collapse="\n")
v[[7]]$label<-paste(intersect(A,B),collapse="\n")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v)
```

Comment: Hi Radha. Welcome to SO! I've edited your question to add the pictures and clean up some of the formatting. I've also changed the question title. When you're writing a question title, please avoid any uninformative language like "Please help" etc., and ask a direct, informative question as succinctly as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to your approach you can add the text as follows:

```
grid.text(x=c(0.5,0),y=c(0.1,0), label = paste(setdiff(S,c(A,B)), collapse=" "))
```

The desired position can be adjusted with the x and y arguments.

Comment: Great! feel free to accept this answer with the tick on the left.