# How do I add values that do not belong to any of the three sets in DiagramVenn (draw.triple.venn)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, venn-diagram

I have created a Venn Diagram using draw.triple.venn, as it appears in the following code snippet, in RStudio:

```
library(VennDiagram)
grid.newpage()
venn1<-draw.triple.venn(area1 = 14, 
                    area2 = 20, 
                    area3 = 30,
                    n12 = 2,
                    n23 = 5,
                    n13 = 4,
                    n123 = 7,
                    fill = c("pink", "green", "orange"),
                    category = c("DH", "CA", "R"))
grid.draw(venn1)
```

I need to locate a value that is not in any of the three sets (for example, 8), as shown in the following graphic:

[image]

How should I modify the code to achieve this?

Comment: I already got the answer in <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847991/r-package-venndiagram-how-can-i-print-values-outside-the-circles?rq=1>?